# Converting Open-Drain to Active-Low

Tags: bjt, open-drain

My question is very similar to [Converting Open-Drain to Active-High](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449788/converting-open-drain-to-active-high-low-voltage-low-power), however instead of an active high, I want an active low.

I am trying to interface [TI BQ51050B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51050b.pdf) (QI receiver + LiPo Charger) and [TI TPS63051](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63051.pdf) (3.3V Buck-Boost) with a 3.7V LiPo. The BQ CHG pin is an open drain output pin, and the TPS EN pin is an input (1: enabled, 0: disabled).

My thinking is that when the battery is charging(CHG-> GND), I don't want it to be attached to any load(EN->LOW), and when the battery isn't charging(CHG->Hi-Z), It should be attached to the load(EN->HIGH).

| Input(CHG) | Output(EN) |
| --- | --- |
| GND | LOW |
| Hi-Z | HIGH |

I was thinking of just using the circuit in the previously mentioned post with a NOT gate attached to the output which would give:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHbx68.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the CircuitLab simulation, I get the desired results on EN (3.7V when CHG is Hi-Z, 11mV when CHG is shorted to GND).

However, I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. If this is the best way, would the [NXP BCW29](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/BCW29_BCW30-1541869.pdf) work for Q2 and the [NXP PMBT3904](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PMBT3904-2938457.pdf) work for Q3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An open drain just means that a MOSFET internally connects the pin to ground inside the IC:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsRx7M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output being Hi-Z just means that the MOSFET is switched off. When the MOSFET is switched on, the output is pulled to ground.

If you want to turn the Hi-Z state to a logical HIGH, all you need is a pullup resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsTuSD.png)</sup>

When the output is in a Hi-Z state, the MOSFET is off and the resistor pulls the output voltage up to 3.3V. When the output is in an active-low state, the MOSFET is on and pulls the output voltage down to 0V.

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: No worries. Really easy to miss the simple solutions sometimes :)